# How to design a dynamically changing table structure in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, frontend

I'm designing a Master table A, it has a sub-table B associated with it, and B has a Sub-table C associated with it, and C finally has 2 sub-tables associated with it, which are D and E.

The structure looks like this:

[image]

If the user clicks '+' on B, the table B, C and D and E must be added additionally. If the user clicks the '+' sign on E, only the table E must be added. Below is the code which takes in table ID and adds a row to the existing table. I was able to get the E table to add additional rows, but here is where I am trying to figure out how to add an entire table structure, based on the table that the user clicks the '+' sign to add or '-' to remove.

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are tabular. Each has multiple rows based on the data queried.

Comment: You have to keep state of tables. It is up to you how you keep state. If you want you save id into element which you clicked. You can save state into dt-id attribute. If user click it opens related table id

Comment: Thanks. Are there any links that you maybe able to provide me I can look into? I see dt has a subelement, associated with it, how do we have that subelement behave as a master element inturn?

Comment: Isn't it possible to achieve with templates?

Comment: Karthik, I would like to see the way you envisioned the solution.  Can you please provide a reference or a link so I can go through?